# Client certificate authentication over HTTP (without HTTPS)

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, authentication, client-certificates

Can client certificates be used for authentication without HTTPS, only over HTTP on Windows IIS platform with ASP.NET ?

I need to authenticate a client using a digital certificate and i can't use HTTPS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use SSL certificate without using a HTTPS connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636499/can-i-use-ssl-certificate-without-using-a-https-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, at least if the client is a web-browser. Moreover, it doesn't have any sense.

Comment: thanks kan for your quick response! can you explain this to me a bit more, why does it not make sense? if i want to know who the client is but i don't want a secure channel

Comment: If you don't have a secure channel, then everybody could steal client's identity, and you will not know is it genuine client or a hacker which has stolen client's identity.

Comment: @kan, your answer is not totally correct, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636499/can-i-use-ssl-certificate-without-using-a-https-connection

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker Why?? The question you mentioned says only about WS-Security. The WS is not a web-browser. The one way to do it: implement X.509 using JavaScript, but I am not sure if it gonna work, at least due to performance issues. And not sure how a client would provide client cert to the JavaScript.

Comment: There's a misconception here. Certificates are not SSL. It's SSL that uses certificates, but certificates were born before SSL. Consequently yes, you can use X.509 certificates without SSL (you can sign the request and put the signature to, for example, HTTP headers). You can use certificates with SSL but without SSL encryption.

From a web-browser point of few you're right. But other types of clients (B2B, web services) might use this scheme. It can be used to verify the client.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker The original question mentions ASP, I assumed that it is about a web application, and my answer mentions browser as well. In this context my answer is correct. WS is unrelated, because it doesn't even need http and IIS in common case.

Comment: I use ASP.Net for general web service communication without any webbrowser. The OP only mentions ASP.Net, but this does not imply the OP is using a webbrowser. OP only talks about IIS as a host and HTTP as a communication protocol.

Comment: @kan - While it would require a custom solution, there certainly is a point.  If someone is unable to use SSL (for example due to IP address limitations), using a client certificate still allows for secure authentication over HTTP by having a challenge encrypted with the user's public key and returned to the server encrypted with the servers public key and signed by the client's private key.